# When should I call the SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option for a STREAM socket

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have two networks on my machine each one on a different NIC.
I have a TCP socket, I am binding the socket (regular bind) to the IP address of network 1, and bindtodevice to my ip address on the other network.

Now I have a question when shall I set the socket option SO_BINDTODEVICE before accept & connect or after the connect & accept ?

most people say it should be before, but it doesn't work !
if I try to set it before the accept (at accept side) connect in the other side returns Errno:  connection refused. and when I try to set it before connect (at connect side) connect returns Errno: connection timeout.

I use RedHat 6.2

Comment: "*I am binding the socket (regular bind) to the IP address of network 1, and bindtodevice to my ip address on the other network.*" What are you trying to achieve doing so? If you want to bind to all addresses available just bind to `INADDR_ANY` (`IN6ADDR_ANY` for IpV6).

Comment: I don't want to bind on INADDR_ANY, I want to check how bindtodevice works on a library that works as kernel and at the same time check how bind to device works at kernel

Comment: If you bind a socket to a device (using `SO_BINDTODEVICE`) only packets send to this specific device are received by the socket, so the other call to `bind()` is useless.

Comment: I know that, It works with me on UDP ,, I need to test it for TCP

Comment: "*most people say it should be before*" so there are indeed people saying you should do this after a successfull `accept()`/`connect()`?

Comment: "*I need to test it*" Test exactly what, please?

Comment: I need to try it with listen socket, I tried it with accepted socket and connected, but the behavior doesn't sound good

Comment: test the SO_BINDTODEVICE option

Comment: Then do not call `bind()`.